# Objective C - Loading a UIView from nib?

Tags: objective-c, subclass, nsbundle, loadnibnamed

I have a base class that initializes itself from a `nib` file.
How can I inherit from this `class`.
Every time I init a `subclass` of it it creates an object of the base class instead of the actual `class` I am trying to create

#### Base Class

```
@implementation BaseClass
- (id)init{
   self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseClass" 
                                          owner:self 
                                        options:nil] lastObject] retain];
   if (self){
   }

   return self;
}

@end
```

#### A Class

```
@implementation MyClass //Inheriting from BaseClass
- (void)init {
   self = [super init];

   if (self) {
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)methodSpecificToThisClass {
   //do something
}
@end
```

#### Usage

```
// It crashes when I call 'methodSpecificToThisClass' 
// because the type that has been created is a type 
// of my BaseClass instead of MyClass
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
[myClass methodSpecificToThisClass];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're always loading objects from the same nib file, you always get the same objects. If the object in the nib is of type `BaseClass`, then you're going to get an object of type `BaseClass` when you load the nib. It doesn't matter that you're alloc'ing a `MyClass` -- the thing that you alloc doesn't come into play because you assign `self` to the loaded object. (In fact, since you never release the alloc'ed memory before reassigning `self`, you're leaking the alloc'ed memory.) It also doesn't matter that you've declared the pointer as a `MyClass*` -- that lets you call `-methodSpecificToThisClass` without getting a complaint from the compiler, but it doesn't change the fact that the actual object is an instance of `BaseClass`. When you do call that method, you get an "unimplemented selector" error when the runtime tries to resolve the selector and finds that it doesn't exist for that object.

If you want to load a `MyClass` from a nib, you're going to have to use a nib that contains a `MyClass` instead of a `BaseClass`.

Comment: Seems like in Objective C you cannot inherit UIElements being created from a nib. So I ended up populating my UI Elements in code instead of populating from a nib.

Comment: @aryaxt: Right. Think of it this way: the nib file contains objects that have already been created, and loading the nib just copies those objects into memory. You can't change the type of an object once it has been created.

Answer (score 3):

Change `self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BaseClass" owner:self options:nil] lastObject] retain];` to    `self = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil] lastObject] retain];`

This is of course assuming you have separate nibs foe each view type.

Comment: I use 1 nib file for all inheriting classes and it's called "BaseClass" so calling what you mentioned would return nil because it won't find the nib file with that name

Comment: If you only have a base class in the nib, how do you expect to extract something else out of it?